# Training a Network designed using tensorflow.keras.Model and the keras functional API causes Python crash

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

-Keras Version: 2.3.1
-Tensorflow Version: 2.2.0
-OS: Windows 10
-Running on: CPU Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8850H
-Developed in: PyCharm
-Python Version: 3.7

I've made a few attempts at training a network designed using the keras functional API, however training always causes python to crash with the following exit message:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Not other stack trace is provided. Below is a simplified version of the code I'm attempting to run:

```py
import scipy.io as io
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers, losses, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

directory = 'C:\\Dataset'

def simple_generator(dim1, dim2, dim3, batch_size=5):
    while True:
        samples = np.random.random_sample((batch_size, dim1, dim2, dim3))
        targets = np.random.random_sample((batch_size, 3))
        yield samples, targets

example_shape = (1100, 4096, 2)

train_gen = simple_generator(example_shape[0], example_shape[1], example_shape[2], batch_size=10)
val_gen = simple_generator(example_shape[0], example_shape[1], example_shape[2])
test_gen = simple_generator(example_shape[0], example_shape[1], example_shape[2])

input_tensor = Input(shape=example_shape)
preprocess = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(input_tensor)
preprocess = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(preprocess)
preprocess = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=3)(preprocess)

"""   Head 1   """
head_1 = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(preprocess)
head_1 = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(head_1)
head_1 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=3)(head_1)
head_1 = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(head_1)
head_1 = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(head_1)
head_1 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=3)(head_1)
head_1 = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu')(head_1)
head_1 = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu')(head_1)
head_1 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=3)(head_1)
head_1 = layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(head_1)

"""   Head 2   """
head_2 = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(preprocess)
head_2 = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(head_2)
head_2 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=3)(head_2)
head_2 = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(head_2)
head_2 = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(head_2)
head_2 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=3)(head_2)
head_2 = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu')(head_2)
head_2 = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu')(head_2)
head_2 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=3)(head_2)
head_2 = layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(head_2)

"""   Head 3   """
head_3 = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(preprocess)
head_3 = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(head_3)
head_3 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=3)(head_3)
head_3 = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(head_3)
head_3 = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(head_3)
head_3 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=3)(head_3)
head_3 = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu')(head_3)
head_3 = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu')(head_3)
head_3 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=3)(head_3)
head_3 = layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(head_3)

concat_out = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([head_1, head_2, head_3])
concat_out = layers.Flatten()(concat_out)
output_tensor = layers.Dense(3)(concat_out)
model = Model(input_tensor, output_tensor)

model.compile(loss=losses.mean_absolute_error, optimizer='sgd')
model.summary()

history = model.fit(x=train_gen, steps_per_epoch=25, epochs=12, validation_data=val_gen, validation_steps=10, verbose=True)
model.save(directory + '\\divergent_network.h5')
evaluations = model.evaluate_generator(generator=test_gen, steps=20, verbose=True)
print(evaluations)
```

Can anyone explain the crash or suggest any potential solutions? I run this code in an Anaconda environment, however I have tried running in a basic python virtual environment to see if it was an Anaconda issue, but I saw no difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been an issue with my conda environment. I made a new "bare minimum" environment with only the packages I needed and that cleared everything up. The info I used to do this can be found at:

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. What exactly was the root cause?

Comment: In my case it was due to issues with my python environment, I believe I had used conda install for some packages and then pip install for others, which then resulted in some packages being installed incorrectly or invisibly to others. My solution was to open Anaconda prompt and create a new environment and install all relevant packages at creation time, allowing conda to handle versioning and file structure. From that point on all new installs were done using conda. You can of course avoid anaconda and install a new python environment yourself and then install all relevant packages using pip.

Comment: The only thing I installed outside of Conda was OpenAI Gym, which is unlikely to be the source of the problem and can't be installed via Conda

Comment: The only thing I could say then is that it's some version mismatch that's not being flagged. Is every package of a compatible version?